# Equivalents of Google Ngram for Japanese

Tags: resources

Are there any equivalents of Google Ngram for Japanese?

[Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams) doesn't currently cover Japanese, and the only other thing I could find was http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/Catalog/catalogEntry.jsp?catalogId=LDC2009T08 , which seems to be a paid-for service.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but what are you going to do with it? By the way, if you want to parse Japanese sentences, then ChaSen: http://chasen-legacy.sourceforge.jp/ is famous.

Comment: @sawa: I was wanting to find out if the word [ソープランド](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soapland) existed before 1984. My reasoning was that if the word was the result of a "nationwide contest", then it wouldn't have existed beforehand, whereas if that was an urban legend, I'd see uses pre-1984. In the end, I used the English Ngram for the word [soaplands](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=soaplands&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). Conclusion: nationwide contest theory plausible.

Comment: Andrew: For that purpose, you can just do an ordinary search, you don't need N-gram. And that story is not an urban legend. It is a famous established story.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I don't know of an Ngram equivalent, but for this particular question there are many sources repeating the 1984 date, and a "Google Books" search finds nothing earlier: http://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5-osT5TuLcL0mAXcpq3QDw&ved=0CBcQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1900%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F1%2F1986&tbm=bks

Comment: As a programmer and NLP specialist, I could easily write a similar program to google ngram. However, I would need an enormous corpus, the size of Google Books to work with. OCRing kanji is often very difficult, and I'm not sure there's much in the way of a Japanese Google Books equivalent to use. tl;dr: give me enough data and its totally do-able.

Comment: It seems like they've got it working for Chinese, so I wonder why they can't get it going for JP. I wonder if fuzzy word boundaries are a greater problem in JP than in ZH.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google Japan sells the Japanese version of "Google Ngram".
Here is the site: http://www.gsk.or.jp/catalog/GSK2007-C

But the site is only in Japanese. There might be the same site in English, though.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Some additional information is on [Google Japan Blog](http://googlejapan.blogspot.com/2007/11/n-gram.html), but this page is also in Japanese.

Comment: The page is available in English: http://www.gsk.or.jp/en/catalog/GSK2007-C/